# Specify output directory for R script with knit_hooks$set(purl = hook_purl)

Tags: r, knitr

I understand that we shouldn't `purl()` a chunk with `knitr`but instead use `knit_hooks$set(purl = hook_purl)`. That works, but it puts the R script in the working directory. I would like to put it in an `R/` directory. It's probably due to my own incompetence, but I couldn't find anything about specifying the directory for the R script (I looked in the R documentation as well as several places online). Anyone have any ideas? I'm knitting from within RStudio, by the way.

Comment: You can generate the script under the current directory, and `file.rename()` it to `R/`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Do you want to put this as an answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the script under the current directory, and `file.rename()` it to the `R/` directory.